# Does copy paper become "old and yellow"?

Tags: consumer-products, chemistry

I have a part-time job at a place where printing, copying, scanning, faxing, and shredding happens every day. Thus, we have about two large cabinets with about 56 reams of paper (packs of 500 sheets) in each cabinet. Of course, even though we use paper every day, we don't use *that* much, so many reams of paper go untouched for nearly 2 months. Then, when the new supply of paper comes in, they usually go right in the more-empty cabinet, leaving the full cabinet (of 2 month old paper) untouched for yet another 2 months.

My coworker (secretary, some lady) keeps telling me that I should make sure to not just keep taking paper from one cabinet, but rather alternate between the two. When I ask her why, she says "because the paper gets old and yellow."

**On what time-scale is this true/significant? If the paper is in a closed cabinet, sealed inside a paper-cover, wouldn't it essentially not change for hundreds of years (if untouched)?**

I can't help but think that this is just some common misconception/myth.

Comment: I don't have links to this, hence this is a comment instead of an answer, but having worked in a laboratory at a pulp processing plant, I can tell you that is absolutely true; it wont need centuries, but it wont happen in a few months. Paper pulp is naturally brown, and has to be bleached white. With time (and temperature), pulp reverts to its natural brown colour. You can observe this effect in old books, as their pages tend to be darker at their outer edges. I have books I bought 30 years ago that have a definitely tan colour.

Comment: I would think how much moisture there is in the air would also be a factor, but I have no source on that.

Comment: Please cite a notable claim.

Comment: Anecdotally I have used paper that must have been years and years old, but that's hardly an answer. (And I am surprised this question is on skeptics.SE... is this really a notable claim? As I have never even hear anybody suggest anything like this)

Comment: @DavidMulder Well apparently quite a few of the older folk that I work with take this as fact.

Comment: Nowadays some books and journals, meant to last a long time, are produced using "acid-free paper" ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid-free_paper

Comment: Even if the change is not noticeable in the short time, it's a good advice to alternate, because the unused paper could potentially be there for decades.

Comment: Without a clear claim, it is hard to be sure, but I am guessing they are not referring directly to the paper's ability to be read, but the paper's ability to be processed by copying machines and printers, which can be affected by moisture and temperature. I haven't found a source that suggests that appropriately stored paper copying paper has a limited life-time, though. (Carbonless copy paper does though.)

Answer (score 15):

Your co-worker is right, normal paper deteriorates due to its acidity and due to oxidation.

> Paper in Europe was originally made from cellulose sourced from linen
>   and cotton rags. This made strong paper structures, owing to the long
>   cellulose chains. The degree of polymerisation - a measure of the
>   average number of glucose molecules in a polymer chain - is high for
>   papers made from linen (3500) and cotton (1000-3000), and this means
>   the chains are tightly bound into the fibrils and fibres by extensive
>   hydrogen bonding.
>
> However, following the invention of the printing press and the
>   enormous surge in demand for paper in the nineteenth century, most
>   paper in our hands today is made from cellulose extracted from wood
>   pulp. Cotton and linen sourced cellulose is now usually reserved for
>   special purposes such as banknotes and artists' materials. While wood
>   is a much more readily available source, the resulting paper has
>   shorter cellulose chains (with a degree of polymerisation around
>   600-1000) and a weaker structure.
>
> Wood also contains a variety of other carbohydrates and lignin. Lignin
>   is a three-dimensional polymeric material that gives woody plants
>   their physical strength. However, it reduces the strength of paper by
>   interfering with the way the cellulose fibres assemble. For low value
>   paper items, such as newspapers, cheap books and ephemera (material
>   produced for one-off use but now of historical importance), the wood
>   pulps would only be minimally purified to remove lignin. This means
>   they are often the most fragile and rapidly deteriorating materials.

(Quoted from Michael Seery on the Website of the [Royal Society of Chemistry](http://www.rsc.org/education/eic/issues/2013March/paper-conservation-cellulose-acid-hydrolysis.asp))

Generally, however, this becomes a problem after decades of storage. Storing paper in a closed cabinet a few months longer than necessary will not affect its quality.

Comment: Can you provide some reference for that last paragraph: i.e. "becomes a problem after decades of storage", and "a few months ... will not affect its quality". My personal opinion is that the statement is true, but that may not be the opinion of the OP's coworker; so some reference/evidence would be good (and is, presumably, the reason for posting the question on Skeptics).

Comment: Using their [LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_\(abstract_data_type\)) model, the paper at the bottom of the cabinet could end up staying there for years before it's finally used (perhaps when they buy a new cabinet and invert the stack when the move the existing paper to it), not just a few months.

Comment: -1 Everyone knows paper ages eventually; this question is about the time-scale that happens in.  Only the final paragraph attempts to answer that, and gives no source.

Comment: @ChrisW: Would you really expect a reference for that, other than personal experience?  FWIW, I have documents printed on standard office copy paper that are 10-20 years old, and they have not noticably yellowed yet.

Comment: @jamesqf: Yes, I expect a reference for that.  This is the Skeptics Stackexchange, not Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Just to add a bit, I checked a bunch of papers stored away that are about 18 years old, and I didn't notice any yellowing or significant deterioration. However, some of those papers seem more rough/'harder' than other papers I've seen, but I don't know if they were like that from the beginning.

Comment: I would because [the point of this site is to supply evidence, to give references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2967/2703). Your personal experience should tell you what kind of references to look for. Yours would be a better answer if you would either delete the last paragraph, or find impersonal non-anecdotal evidence to justify it.